# How to retrieve python object from it's string reference

Tags: python, serialization, jinja2, deform

I'm using Deform widgets to display an object's attribute. In my widget serialization method I can see that my *cstruct* is correct:

```
serialization cstruct: [<abc.modules.core.models.Assessment object at 0x105583320>]
```

When trying to display within jinja2 template the objet's property e.g 'created_at' the result is:

```
jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'str object' has no attribute 'created_at'
```

What can I do to have the Assessment object considered as object and not as string within Jinja2? I believe it's very simple but I still can't find out what is wrong. Please help.

A bit more code:
Schema node:

```
class SubcontractorAssessmentSchema(MappingSchema):
    """ **Schema definition for ``Subcontractor Assessment`` part.** """
    readonly = True
    assessments = SchemaNode(String(), widget=LastResultsWidget2(),
                             title='Assessment:', missing='')
```

[...]

Widget:

```
class LastResultsWidget2(SelectWidget):
    """ **Widget for Last Results.** """
    template = 'last_results'
    readonly_template = 'last_results'
    strip = True

    def serialize(self, field, cstruct, **kw):
        """
        Overwritten default serialize of SelectWidget.

        :param field: Field
        :param cstruct: Value of Widget
        :param kw: Additional arguments.
        :return: rendered field.
        """
        if cstruct in (colander.null, None):
            cstruct = self.null_value
#        print ('serialization cstruct: ' +str(cstruct))
        return field.renderer(self.template, field=field, cstruct=cstruct)
```

Comment: don' serialize - send object. And show your code.

Comment: Well as far as I know that's the way it works for Deform widgets. You can't avoid serialization using widgets.

Comment: Is this deform 0.9? Can you clarify the error with full traceback and Jinja 2 template where it happens?

Comment: Because Colander converts the object to string before passing to the widget. You most likely want a custom Colander type, not `colander.String`.

Answer (score 0):

It was an error withi this certain Colader version. It was forcing the widget to behave singleton-like. Thank you for all your hints!